# Why do GNU tools use non-matching ` and ' to quote errors?

Tags: history, gnu

GNU tools often output error and warning messages with parts of the line (e.g. filenames, syntax errors, invalid dates, etc) quoted with non-matching quotes: ` and '

e.g. From the GNU coreutils [FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html):

```
$ date -d "2006-04-02 02:30:00"
date: invalid date `2006-04-02 02:30:00'
```

and

```
rm: cannot remove `backup.tar': Value too large for defined data
```

Why do they do this?  Is there any benefit to it?  What's the history behind it?

Comment: These are just old-school ‘smart quotes’, right?

Comment: i assume that's what they are meant to be.  i'm wondering what made them think it was a good idea.

Comment: I think just because it's the [correct way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Electronic_documents) to write them, especially in light of the early days of electronic character encoding. (But that's pure speculation.)

Comment: seems to be version dependent.  my `date` (date (GNU coreutils) 8.23) outputs `date: invalid date ‘2006-02-31 02:30:00’`  which is `date: invalid date \342\200\2302006-02-31 02:30:00\342\200\231$`, unicode left and right single quotation marks.  the faq entry above uses a backtick and an apostrophe.

Comment: those are the default left and right m4 quotes as well.

Comment: It's been [asked before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ascii+quote+apostrophe).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas i get why it's in man pages and documentation.  but my tty is not a book and my shell is not a reference manual. if they used plain single or double quotes, it would be possible to copy-paste the entire quoted string and use it without editing in another command (e.g. grep a log file) or into a google search.

Comment: I don't get your point about copy-paste, but here, it's the same reason as mentioned in the other question, that's for correct typography. It's true there has been a general trend lately in fonts rendering the apostrophe as a vertical bar and the backtick as an oblique one, but in ASCII, the backtick doubles as a left quote and the apostrophe as a right quote, so `\`...'` is still the correct way to quote in English in ASCII and still output correctly with some fonts.  In French locales, you get `«.....»` as is correct in French.

Comment: re: copy-paste, try pasting the quoted string (incl. quotes) from the date example in the FAQ or mine above into, e.g., grep like `grep ‘2006-02-31 02:30:00’ /var/log/messages`.  a silly example but it illustrates the point.  If they were plain single quotes, that would Just Work with no need to edit the command line before hitting enter.  IMO practicality beats some historical ASCII documentation relic.  the workaround is trivial (don't select the quotes for pasting), but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: IOW, you'd like parts of error messages by some utility to be valid code in some random language (POSIX sh)? What about the error message for `date -d "2015'02'03"` ?

Comment: i'd like to know if there's a good reason for the weird quoting before i submit a bug report.  i'm fully aware of the fact that copy-pasting such quoting will be impractical in pathological cases.  it's been a (very minor) annoyance i've known about for a long time...the issue came up in a comment to one of my answers today (OP asked where did the backtick come from) and i though it would make an interesting question.

Comment: [been done already](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2012-01/msg00098.html)

Comment: More info related to this question at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/any-reference-on-the-usage-of-a-backtick-and-single-quotation-mark-like-this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With old X fonts, `..' looked symmetrical like ‛..’

Also given `..' latex generates correct left and right single quotes like ‘..’

So `..' was a hack and in 2012 coreutils [changed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2012-01/msg00096.html) to shell like quoting '..'

Now it wasn't full shell syntax however and would generate corrupted output if there were embedded "\r" chars etc. present. Also inconsistently in some cases no quoting was used, and sometimes unicode ‘..’ quoting was used (which uses quotes as defined for the locale and caters for escaping these control characters).

A very recent (2015) [patch](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/compare/e71be12...6796698) [set](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/compare/00eb7af...d820706) was introduced to coreutils to make this more consistent, by quoting all file name output in shell compat format, which also escapes control characters appropriately, and allows for easier copy and pasting back to other commands. Other items in diagnostics use "full unicode" quoting as mentioned above.

Comment: cool, so no need for me to submit a new bug report.  I just have to wait for the update to make its way to debian sid.  in the meantime, do you know if there's a shell variable I can set (other than, e.g., LANG=C) to control the quoting style?

Comment: only for ls which honors QUOTING_STYLE=shell etc.